# Numbering subsections

Tags: numbering

I'm trying to fix the numbering for the subsections of document I'm putting together. What I have at the moment is something that looks like:

> Chapter 1
>   ------Section 1.1
>   ------Section 1.2
>   ------Section 1.3
>   -----------Subsection 1.3.7

and similar in later chapters as well.

But I want subsection 1.3.7 to be numbered as 1.3.1. It seems the reason it's getting numbered as 1.3.7 is because I have some definitions and theorems within section 1.3 that are numbered 1.3.1 - 1.3.6

I've looked around at other questions about numbering, but none of them seem to address this particular issue

Comment: Could you post a minimal, yet complete, code reproducing the problem?

Comment: you seem to have managed to use the subsection counter for the definitions.

Comment: latex would start the numbering from 1 so you have broken the default behaviour with code you have not shown. That makes it hard to tell you how to fix it if you show no code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not given many clues but looking into a crystal ball suggests that you have

[image]

from

```
\documentclass{report}

\newtheorem{thm}[subsection]{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Zzz}
\section{Z}
z
\section{Zz}
z
\section{Zzz}
z
\begin{thm} aaa\end{thm}
\begin{thm} aaa\end{thm}
\begin{thm} aaa\end{thm}
\begin{thm} aaa\end{thm}
\begin{thm} aaa\end{thm}
\begin{thm} aaa\end{thm}
\subsection{zzzz}
zzz
\end{document}
```

where the `[subsection]` optional argument says to number the theorems as subsections. The solution is not to use that argument.

Comment: My apologies for not providing a MWE. You are correct that the [subsection] argument was the culprit. Thank you!